# Solving a recurrence for a probability?

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

I came across the following recurrence relation when exploring properties of a certain type of randomized perfect binary tree:

$$
T(0) = \frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
T(k + 1) = 1 - T(k)^2
$$

(Specifically, this is the probability that a random, complete binary tree of height $k$ with values at the leaves and where each internal node is a NAND gate will evaluate to 1.)

I was able to get values for this recurrence by writing a quick Python script and found that it quickly starts to oscillate between values very close to 0 and 1 once $k$ gets large.  However, I don't have a closed-form expression for the recurrence.

I have never encountered a recurrence like this one before (most recurrences I know of come from the analysis of recursive algorithms or data structures, which rarely have squared terms arise).  Is there a standard technique for solving recurrences of this sort?  If so, how can I use them to solve this recurrence?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with applying differential equations to the series?

Comment: @abiessu- I have a basic exposure to generating functions and manipulating recurrences that way.  I assume the idea would be to set up the generating functions and use derivatives to make the squares go away?

Comment: Some discouragement: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147075/why-is-solving-non-linear-recurrence-relations-hopeless

Comment: Some problems like these are mentioned here http://neilsloane.com/doc/doubly.html but it doesn't seem likely you will find much help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nonlinear recurrences are notoriously difficult to solve and sometimes quite surprisingly complex (see [logistic map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map)).

In this case, the limiting behaviour can be guessed by writing the two-step recursion:

$$x_{n+2} = x_n^2 \, (2 -x_n^2)$$

and, because the graph $y=x^2(2-x^2)$ is strictly below $y=x$ for $x\in [0,1/2]$ the recursion goes to zero (of course, this implies that $x_n$ will tend to 1 for odd $n$).

Comment: That's a great way to think about it.  I didn't realize how hard this sort of problem is to solve!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it's the **[logistic map](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html)**!

Define
$\displaystyle{T\left(n\right) \equiv \mu\left(x_{n} - {1 \over 2}\right)}$ where
$\displaystyle{\mu \in {\mathbb R}}$ is a constant to be determined.
$\displaystyle{x_{0} = {1 \over 2}\left(1 + {1 \over \mu}\right)}$. Then

$$
\mu\left(x_{n + 1} - {1 \over 2}\right)
=
1 - \left\lbrack\mu\left(x_{n} - {1 \over 2}\right)\right\rbrack^{2}
=
1 - {1 \over 4}\,\mu^{2} + \mu^{2}x_{n}\left(1 - x_{n}\right)
$$

$$
x_{n + 1} = {1 \over 2} + {1 \over \mu} - {1 \over 4}\,\mu + \mu x_{n}\left(1 - x_{n}\right)
$$

Set $\displaystyle{{1 \over 2} + {1 \over \mu} - {1 \over 4}\,\mu = 0}$ such that
$\displaystyle{\mu_{\pm} = 1 \pm \sqrt{\,5\,}}$. We choose
$\displaystyle{\mu = 1 + \sqrt{\,5\,}}$. Finally

$$
\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{rcl}
\\[3mm]&&
\\
x_{n + 1} & = & \mu\,x_{n}\left(1 - x_{n}\right)
\\[4mm]
\mu & = & 1 + \sqrt{\,5\,} \approx 3.2360679775
\\[4mm]
x_{0} & = & {1 \over 2}\,\left(1 + {1 \over \mu}\right) = {3 + \sqrt{\,5\,} \over 8}
\approx
0.65450849718
\\[4mm]
T\left(n\right) & = & \mu\left(x_{n} - {1 \over 2}\right)
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\mu <\ T\left(n\right)\ < {1 \over 2}\,\mu
\\[3mm]&&
\end{array}\right.
$$

By using well known properties of the Logistic Map you can find many interesting properties of your system. With the parameters given above, $\displaystyle{T\left(n\right)}$ converges to 2 values: $0$ and $1$ which are fixed points. In addition, $\displaystyle{\sqrt{\,5\,} - 1 \over 2}$ is another fixed point besides the negative fixed point $\displaystyle{-\,{\sqrt{\,5\,} + 1 \over 2}}$.

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
T(0) & = & 0.5\\
T(1) & = & 0.75\\
T(2) & = & 0.4375\\
T(3) & = & 0.808594\\
T(4) & = & 0.346176\\
T(5) & = & 0.880162\\
T(6) & = & 0.225315\\
T(7) & = & 0.949233\\
T(8) & = & 0.0989562\\
T(9) & = & 0.990208\\
T(10) & = & 0.0194888\\
T(11) & = & 0.99962\\
T(12) & = & 0.00075948\\
T(13) & = & 0.999999\\
T(14) & = & 1.15362e-06\\
T(15) & = & 1\\
T(16) & = & 2.66151e-12\\
T(17) & = & 1\\
T(18) & = & -1.79638e-16
\end{array}
$$

Comment: How is the last term negative?  This sequence should never evaluate to a negative number since each value in the range (0, 1) ensures the next term is in the range (0, 1).

Comment: It should be a rounding error when $T(k) \lesssim 1$. Maybe (numerically) we should write $(1 - T)(1 + T)$ instead of $1 - T^{2}$.