# Finding general term for sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$a_{n+1}=3a_n^2+2$,$a_1=1$

I want to do $log$ to kill the square but I don't how

I can let the coefficient 3 be 1

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{3^{2^{n+1}-1}}=(\frac{a_n}{3^{2^n-1}})^2+\frac{2}{3^{2^n-1}}$

But it seems more complicated

I don't know how to do it

Thanks!

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+a%28n%2B1%29%3D3a%28n%29%5E2%2B2%2C+a%281%29%3D1&x=9&y=7) can't do it, so it's probably difficult.

Comment: Are you sure this is the recursion you want to consider and it can be solved?

Comment: @Did see Marty's answer and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918972/finding-an-explicit-formula-for-a-n-defined-recursively-by-a-n1-a-n26

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks.

Comment: @Did I guess you changed your comment after the system pasted it to my "unread inbox." I suppose i was not clear; I think the two students are working on the same problem. To the best of my knowledge, only two such problems have closed form solutions, $x_{n+1} = x_n^2$ and $y_{n+1} = y_n^2 - 2.$ For any other, all that can be done is to estimate $C$ in $a_n = C^{2^n},$ but it is not even possible to get $C$ particularly accurate with only a handful of sequence terms, and a tiny error in $C$ makes an enormous difference in $a_n.$

Answer (score 0):

A very partial start,
not in any way complete.

To get rid of the $3$,
let
$a_n
=c b_n
$.
Then
$a_{n+1}=3a_n^2+2
$
becomes
$cb_{n+1}
=3(cb_n)^2+2
=3c^2b_n^2+2
$
or
$b_{n+1}
=3cb_n^2+2/c
$.

Setting
$c = \frac13$,
this becomes
$b_{n+1}
=b_n^2+6
$.

At this point,
we get into nonlinear recurrences,
which generally grow
exponentially.

So I'll leave it at this.

Comment: then that is why the other guy had +6 earlier. Not nice, the only nice ones are $x' = x^2$ and $x' = x^2 - 2.$  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918972/finding-an-explicit-formula-for-a-n-defined-recursively-by-a-n1-a-n26

Answer (score 0):

General method of solving such recurrence relations was designed by S.Rabinovich, G.Berkolaiko and S.Havlin. This method gives solution in the following form:
$$
a_{n}=\langle e|T^n|\gamma \rangle
$$
where $\langle e|=[\delta_{j1}]^\infty_{j=0}-$row-vector, $|\gamma\rangle=\{1\}^\infty_{j=0}-$column-vector, $T-$matrix, which elements defined as $T_{jk}=\binom{j}{k/2}3^{\frac{k}{2}}2^{j-\frac{k}{2}}$.

However, I should admit that derivation of simple expression for $T^n$ is quite competitive task.