# Explicit formulas for non-linear recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

It seems that recurrence relations like [Hofstadter's Q-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter_sequence#Hofstadter_Q_sequence), in which nested calls to the relation occur, i.e. *Q(n) = ...Q(...Q(...)...)...*, don't appear to have explicit formulas listed. My introductory textbooks only offers solutions to various linear ones.

Are there examples of non-linear recurrence relations with explicit formulas, and are there any proofs of non-existence of explicit formulas for other non-linear recurrence relations, or are they simply "[hopeless](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147075/why-is-solving-non-linear-recurrence-relations-hopeless)" to figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it goes without saying, but if you have any linear recurrence relation you can turn it into a non-linear one. For example, $F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)$ is for Fibonacci numbers. Let $a(n) = b ^{F(n)}$. Then, $a(n) = a(n-1)a(n-2)$, but, since $F(n)$ has an explicit formula, so does $a(n)$. Moreover, there are many sequences that have explicit summation formulas that have second degree or higher recurrence relations. There are many examples in [the OEIS](http://oeis.org), such as [sequence A000166](http://oeis.org/A000166), the number of derangements.

Answer (score 1):

yes, for example the Catalan numbers have a non-linear reccurence relation but there is an explicit formula for them