# Non linear recursion

Tags: recurrence-relations

Is there any general method to solve a non linear recurrence relation. For example:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}f_{n+1}&=&2f_{n}^2-1 \\
f_1&=&4
\end{eqnarray}$$

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: For the linear case, closed solutions are available. For the non linear case, closed form solutions may be found only in particular situations.

Comment: No general method exists. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147075/why-is-solving-non-linear-recurrence-relations-hopeless) for a discussion

Comment: the two nice  monic quadratic without linear terms are $a_{n+1} = a_n^2 $   and $b_{n+1} = b_n^2 - 2  .$  Maybe there is a useful way to express your $f_n$  in terms of $b_n$

Comment: This problem has solution $f_n=\cosh(2^{n-1}\operatorname{arcosh}4)$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Inverse_functions_as_logarithms) if those functions are unfamiliar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TO SAVE WRITING, I am going to change the initial index, instead of $f_1 = 4$ I  am switching to $\color{red}{f_0=4}$

that worked. Let $   g_n = 2 f_n, $   so that $f_n = \frac{g_n}{2}.$  This leads to $\color{red}{g_0=8}$

We get to the solvable $$  g_{n+1} = g_n^2 - 2  $$

I like to write this as $$g_0 =  G + \frac{1}{G}, $$ then
$$g_1 =  G^2 + \frac{1}{G^2}, $$
$$g_2 =  G^4 + \frac{1}{G^4}, $$
$$g_3 =  G^8 + \frac{1}{G^8}, $$
generally
$$g_n =  G^{2^n} + \frac{1}{G^{2^n}}, $$

From $\color{red}{g_0=8}$  we need $  G + \frac{1}{G}=8, $   we may take $G = 4 + \sqrt{15}$   and $\frac{1}{G} = 4 - \sqrt{15}$